# How Instagram Real Time Subscription works

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am following this link [Instagram Real time updates tag - getting empty data, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203878/instagram-real-time-updates-tag-getting-empty-data-why) to implement Instagram Real Time Subscription.

I am thinking do I need to hit the url every time in order to check the new update, how is gonna work?. Some are using nodejs, socketio,etc, which I dont want to get into this.

What I am trying to achieve through this that every time is a new update, It starts getting analytic automatically without letting my system know which image to mointor.(I already implemented this part), but stuck on the real time.

Any suggestion to that.

Comment: PHP, Following URL mentioned on post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need socketio.
https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/?hl=en

1. You subscribe to something passing an url that will be used for answers
2. Everytime there is an update instagram will send you a payload to the url you passed during your subscription.

The point of subscription: You create a subscription (you'll give some parameters, client_id, client_secret and the url you want instagram to call when there is an update, check the documentation for details).

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
     -F 'object=user' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
     -F 'callback_url=http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

Each time the media you subscribed to is updated instagram will send you new data to the urlcallback you provided in the subscription.

I hope it helps you to understand how it works. Read the documentation throghroughly.

you **NEED** to read the documentation =D From the documentation:

*"When someone posts a new photo and it triggers an update of one of your subscriptions, we make a POST request to the callback URL that you defined in the subscription"*.

Comment: For example: xyz.com/callback.php is my callback url on subscription, How do I know? From where I can check this? Sorry too many questions

Comment: How do you know what ? what part of the documentation is a problem for you ?

Comment: I am just confused how I know there is an update from code, Based on update I want to perform some actions. Suppose callback.php contains my code and action code too. So how my code executes based on real time, Do I need to hit the URL everytime via cronjob or something. I know sounds stupid but I am really confused on this.

Comment: I edited my answer but you question about cronjob shows that you should first read the documentation with more attention.

Comment: So It will work automatically? So I dont need to hit the url everytime?.

Comment: That's the point of a subscription. That's also why you NEED to read the documentation =D From the documentation: "When someone posts a new photo and it triggers an update of one of your subscriptions, we make a POST request to the callback URL that you defined in the subscription. "

Comment: The link in this answer is dead. Maybe this is now at https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/ ? I would correct this myself, but since I didn't know what he former link was referencing, I didn't know whether this how-to doc was the same.