# No data from tag subscription - Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have two streaming subscriptions with the Instagram API. One for type `user` and the second for type `tag`. Specifically, I'm using the tag *nofilter*.

For the **user** subscription, my server receives the following json from Instagram:

```
[ { changed_aspect: 'media',
    object: 'user',
    object_id: '99999999',
    time: 1447441353,
    subscription_id: 99999999,
    data: { media_id: '0000000000642770215_000000000' } } ]
```

For the **nofilter tag** subscription, my server receives the following json from Instagram. Why is this missing `media_id`?

```
[ { changed_aspect: 'media',
    object: 'tag',
    object_id: 'nofilter',
    time: 1447442900,
    subscription_id: 20700000,
    data: {} } ]
```

Does anyone know why the data attribute in the tag subscription is empty? Shouldn't it contain a `media_id` property and value?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for tag subscriptions is no longer available. It appears only user subscriptions are available now.
https://instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/

You can see the now deprecated documentation here.
https://instagram.com/developer/deprecated/realtime/

Regardless, for reference, tag subscriptions are only a notification which you then need to query the tags endpoint to retrieve actual data.

[Instagram Real time updates tag - getting empty data, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203878/instagram-real-time-updates-tag-getting-empty-data-why)

Comment: Do I get it right, that I now have no other possibility of getting updates in realtime about some tags?

Comment: Do you know any tutorial or explanation on how one can get realtime instagram messages working again?

Comment: At this point there is no real-time feed. What I've created is a function that hits the tags endpoint every few seconds and traverses through the paged results. Those results are saved in mongo using ID's from Instagram as keys, so duplicates are ignored. At this point the code is private, if it is ever open sourced, ill be sure to update my answer

Comment: I thought in such direction, but this is a bit too much work right now. I would try this out if I will have enough time! Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @chAlexey I've put the code up here: https://github.com/dego89/node-instagram. Have a look at that repo and see if anything helps